# Upper bound on a integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $h(x)$ be a smooth periodic function on $(0,T)$.

$\int_0^Th(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=c\in(0,\infty),h(x)\in(0,1)\,\forall\, x\in(0,T)$

Possible to obtain an upper bound of $\int_0^T\frac{h(x)}{1-h(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$ in terms of $c$ ?

Comment: hint: expand the integrand in a geometric series

Comment: But then how do I bound powers of $h(x)$? what inequality am I looking for?

Comment: never mind i got it. just the LP norm embedding. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

You said $h$ was smooth. First a non-smooth counterexample: Say $T=2$, $c=1$. For $1/2<r<1$ define $$h(t)=\begin{cases}
r,&(0<t<1/r),
\\0,&(1/r\le t<T).\end{cases}$$Then $\int_0^Th(t)\,dt=c$, but $$\int_0^T\frac{h(t)}{1-h(t)}\,dt=\frac1{1-r},$$which blows up as $r\to1$.

That's a counterexample except it's not smooth. But if there were an upper bound for smooth functions the same upper bound would apply to a function like $h$ above. How you prove that depends on what you know - I don't know what you know. But informally, imagine a function $g$ just like the $h$ above except it's been altered a bit near the discontinuities to be smooth; that function is *equal* to $h$ on, say, the interval $(1/10,9/10)$, and so the integral of $g/(1-g)$ is larger than $(4/5)/(1-r)$.